# Como tirar o refresh da página inteira quando usa o componente FileUpload do primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou usando o componente `FileUpload` do primefaces no `mode="simple"` e está funcionado normal. Mas quando eu clico no botão para salvar em uma determinada pasta, ele dá refresh na página toda. Tem como tirar isso?

Abaixo está o meu código XHTML:

```xml
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form"><p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
            closable="true" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2" style="font-size: 10px" id="panelGrid1">
        <h:panelGroup id="panelGroup1" >
            <p:outputLabel for="nomeTexto" value="Nome do Texto: " rendered="#{parametrizacaoTagsControl.tipoTag == 1}" />
            <p:inputText id="nomeTexto"
                value="#{parametrizacaoTagsControl.nomeTexto}" rendered="#{parametrizacaoTagsControl.tipoTag == 1}" />

            <p:fileUpload value="#{parametrizacaoTagsControl.file}"
                mode="simple" skinSimple="true" rendered="#{parametrizacaoTagsControl.tipoTag == 2}" label="Escolher arquivo"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <p:separator />
        <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="2" style="font-size: 10px"  id="panelGrid2" >
            <p:commandButton value="Incluir" ajax="false"
                actionListener="#{parametrizacaoTagsControl.upload}"
                disabled="#{!parametrizacaoTagsControl.habilitaBotoes}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Já tentou usar ajax?

Comment: ele já esta funcionando, só não quero que ele fica dando refresh na tela toda.

Comment: É isso mesmo que o @Patrick comentou. Use ajax. Deixe o `ajax="true"` e atualize o `<h:form>` com `update="@form"`.

Comment: Se eu deixa como true o ajax ele para de funcionar.

Comment: Você vai ter que mudar seu código. ñ basta simplesmente colocar ajax. procure no google: ajax primefaces upload

Answer (score 1):

A única forma de você manter o estado da página (sem refresh) ao fazer um `submit` é via `AJAX`.
Não existe o atributo `ajax` no componente `p:fileUpload`. Para ativar o ajax você deve alterar o `mode="simple"` (sem ajax) para `mode="advanced"` (com ajax) e adicionar o atributo `fileUploadListener`.

**Segue o passo a passo:**

**1** - Adicione o método para receber o arquivo no seu bean `ParametrizacaoTagsControl`:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
        file = event.getFile();
}
```

**2** - Altere seu `p:fileUpload`:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{parametrizacaoTagsControl.handleFileUpload}" 
    rendered="#{parametrizacaoTagsControl.tipoTag == 2}" mode="advanced" 
    update="fileContainer" label="Escolher arquivo" />

<h:panelGroup id="fileContainer" layout="block">
   <ui:fragment rendered="#{parametrizacaoTagsControl.file!=null}">
       <p>Nome do arquivo: #{parametrizacaoTagsControl.file.fileName}</p>
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Estou utilizando um `h:panelGroup` só para você ver o ajax em ação.
Preste muita atenção no atributo `update` pois é nele que você informa o que será atualizado.